# AVAssetExportSession gives -620 error (insufficient physical memory) with 4 gigs free RAM

Tags: objective-c, macos, avassetexportsession

This problem has been driving me crazy.  I am trying to tag some songs in my Cocoa application using an AVAsset which I am adding the tag info to it and exporting it with AVAssetExportSession.  However, no matter what I do, the export fails with the error `(OSStatus error -620.)" (notEnoughMemoryErr: insufficient physical memory)`.  On my MacBook I always have 3-4 gigs or more of free RAM when I am doing this, so that can't be right.  I tried removing all the tag information, in case that was causing an error somewhere, but that didn't help.

Here is the code:

```
AVURLAsset *asset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[tempSongPath stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]] options:nil];

AVAssetExportSession *session;
session = [AVAssetExportSession exportSessionWithAsset:asset presetName:AVAssetExportPresetAppleM4A];
session.outputFileType = AVFileTypeAppleM4A;

NSURL *outputURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@Path/%@", NSTemporaryDirectory(), @"output.m4a"] stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

session.outputURL = outputURL;
NSLog(@"Asset: %@", asset);
NSLog(@"Session %@", session);
[session exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^{


    if (AVAssetExportSessionStatusCompleted == session.status) {
        NSLog(@"Completed");
    }

    NSString *cause;
    NSString *stringError;
    if (session.error)
    {
        NSLog(@"%@", session.error);
        stringError = [session.error localizedDescription];
        cause = session.error.localizedFailureReason;

    }
    else
        stringError = @"Unknown error";
    NSLog(@"Error: %@ because %@", stringError, cause);
    for (NSString *key in session.error.userInfo.allKeys)
    {
        NSLog(@"%@: %@", key, [session.error.userInfo objectForKey:key]);
    }
}];
```

Any help at all?  I've been stuck on this problem for two full days.

Comment: How much RAM is your application using at the moment of the crash and is your application 32-bit or 64-bit? If it is 32-bit and it is trying to allocate more than 4GB of RAM to the application, it will run out of RAM no matter how much free RAM you have as that is the limit for 32-bit apps.

Comment: @BergQuester My application is using about 40 MB of RAM at the time of crash.  Also, I don't think that it is possible to write a 32 bit application for OSX. (I could be wrong about that though)

Comment: I'd be curious how much RAM it's trying to allocate then. OS X was 32-bit only up until 10.4. I believe full-64-bit support was completed in 10.6. In 10.7 they dropped support for 32-bit CPUs, but 32-bit applications are still supported. Xcode 4.6.3 supports building 32-bit Mac applications as well, we still have a 32-bit version of our application at work that we build with 4.6.3.

Comment: @BergQuester I'm no expert but I don't think that exporting a single song should cause it to try to allocate 3-4 gigs of RAM.

Comment: I'm inclined to agree, but something is making it think that it is running out of RAM. I'm not very familiar with AVAsset myself. I'd suggest running the Leaks Instrument against your app. It will give you insight to your RAM usage and if you have any leaks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The out-of-memory error is a red herring. The problem is this line:

```
NSURL *outputURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@Path/%@", NSTemporaryDirectory(), @"output.m4a"] stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

Try replacing it with this:

```
NSURL *outputURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", NSTemporaryDirectory(), @"output.m4a"] isDirectory:NO];
```

I've just tested with the above and it now works fine.

Comment: (NB You'll still get an NSLog message along the lines of `Error: Unknown error because (null)` because you're logging an error even when `session.error` is clear)

Comment: That works! But why didn't mine work?  When I do it your way I get `file://localhost/var/folders/l8/jzvsxgpn5t5cgc3wjk39wq380000gn/T//output.m4a` for `outputURL` with that double / instead of one.  That is why I didn't put it the / in the string.  But for some reason it works with two slashes and not one.  Why is that?

Comment: The issue stems from the fact that you used `URLWithString` rather than `fileURLWithPath`, so your URL wasn't prepended with 'file://localhost'.